# Check if textbox contains domain extensions without being repetitive

Tags: .net, vb.net, contains

I am trying to check if my textbox contains .com .net .org etc. without being repetitive.

Current code:

```
If textbox1.Text.Contains(".org") Or textbox1.Text.Contains(".com") Or textbox1.Text.Conatins(".net") Then
    browser.Load(textbox1.Text)
End If
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? Example:

```
If textbox1.Text.Contains(".org", ".com", ".net", ".us", ".edu") Then
    browser.Load(textbox1.Text)
End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write your check in this way

```
Dim ext As String() = {".org", ".com", ".net", ".us", ".edu"} 
Dim content = textbox1.Text.ToLower()
If ext.Any(Function(x) content.Contains(x)) Then
    Console.WriteLine("Found")
End If
```

First declare an array with your extensions to check, then use the IEnumerable extension [Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx) to examine one by one your extensions against the content of the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is add the extensions to a `List(Of String)` one by one or add them to a text file and read it.

```
Dim extList As New List(Of String)

Private sub test()
extlist.Add(File.ReadAllLines(filepathhere))
For each item in extList
  If mytextbox.Text.Contains(item) Then
  'your code here
  End if
Next
End sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This could work (not tested)

```
Select Case Right(textbox1.text, 4)
    Case ".org", ".com", ".net"
        browser.load(textbox1.text)
End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Dim pattern As string = "\.(org|com|net|us|edu)"
If Regex.IsMatch(textbox1.text, pattern) Then
  browser.Load(textbox1.Text)
End If
```